# Not getting http error codes from rest calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, aurelia

#### I need to be able to differentiate between a 400 and 500 range error code for different flows in our application.

Lets say I have 3 rest calls,

- First will return 200,
- second will return 401,
- and third will return 502

I started using `aurelia-http-client`, which is where I first noticed that I was getting the http error `code = 0` in the promise`s reject callback.

Update: Using `aurelia-fetch-client` returns only a string as a error response, thus wasn't an option either.

I then tried using an `ajax call` and a basic`XMLHttpRequest`, which yielded the same result. For 200 range, I got the codes, but anything above, I received a statusCode of 0.

Update: I am running Version 63.0.3239.132 of Chrome if it makes a difference.

#### What I've tried:

- I've tried about 5 different variations for fetch.

  ```
  fetch(url, {
    method: requestMessage.method,
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(content)
  })
  .then((result) => {
    resolve(result)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    reject(error); 
  });
  ```
- Outputs a string error

Using `aurelia-http-client`

```
    this.httpClient.createRequest(url)
      .asPut()
      .withContent(params)
      .send()
      .then((response) => {
        resolve(response);
      },
      (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
```

- StatusCode is always 0 for errors

Also (This just builds up a dynamic XmlHttpRequest):

```
private retryRequest(): void {
  var xhr = this.setupXhr();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => this.stateChange(xhr);
  setTimeout(() => {
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(this.content));
  }, 1000);
}

private setupXhr(): XMLHttpRequest {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(this.method, this.url, true);
  xhr = this.addHeaders(xhr);
  return xhr;
}

private addHeaders(xhr: XMLHttpRequest): XMLHttpRequest {
  for (let key in this.headers) {
    if (this.headers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader(this.headers[key].key, this.headers[key].value);
    }
  }
  return xhr;
}

private stateChange(xhr: XMLHttpRequest): void {
  logger.debug(' ::>> xhr = ', xhr);
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
      this.resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
    } else if (xhr.status >= 500) {
      this.retryRequest();
    } else {
      // this.retryRequest();
      this.reject(xhr.response); // call after a # of fails for this ??? 
    }
  }
}
```

- Which only returns the 200 range http status codes

Also:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: requestMessage.method,
      url,
      data: JSON.stringify(content),
      headers,
      success: (data) => {
        logger.debug(' ::>> rest call was a success ', data);
        resolve(data);
      },
      statusCode: {
        502: (jqXHR) => {
          logger.debug(' ::>> received 502 ');
          var retryAfter = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Retry-After');
          retryAfter = parseInt(retryAfter, 10);
          if (!retryAfter) { retryAfter = 5 };
          setTimeout(query, retryAfter * 1000);
        }
      }
    });
```

- Which never gets to the 502 callback. I've tried other status codes as well

Is there a way of getting the error codes which I might be missing? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:

I initially thought `Harshal Bulsara`'s was what resolved my issue. It is a nice implementation, but I found the actual issue.

I found that our nginx response didn't send the required headers.
By adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, I received the statusCode.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement and have implemented this using following code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlAjax,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: headerValue,
        data: _dataValue,
        crossDomain: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            //any operation
        },
        complete: function () {
            // any after operation
        },
        success: function (data) {
           // All 2XX will reach here 
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            var Check = JSON.parse(jqXHR['responseText']);
            // In above array you will get whole error response
        }
    }).done(function (rs, textStatus, xhr) {
        // on finished
    });
```

In `jqXHR`, `textstatus` and `errror` params you will receive all the information about errors and codes related to it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately no luck. It seems like this issue might lie with the responses we receive from our server